# Cast an Element to a FlowPanel?

Tags: gwt

I'm trying to create my own compound button, using a div as the outer parent:

```
public class CompoundButton extends ButtonBase {
    public CompoundButton() {
        super(DOM.createDiv());
    }
}
```

the constructor of ButtonBase wants an Element instance, though, so I'm using that DOM.createDiv() call. But how can I add child widgets now at this point?:

```
public CompoundButton() {
    super(DOM.createDiv());  <-- we're just a div.

    // ButtonBase has no "add()" method - but this class is really 
    // just a div instance, so shouldn't I be able to convert it to 
    // a FlowPanel for example to be able to add elements to it here?
    this.add(new FlowPanel());   <-- not possible, "add()" not available here.
```

Thanks

Comment: You can simply use a Label or FlowPanel and style it to look like a button. What do you need from ButtonBase?

Comment: I need to add event handlers to it for mobile devices. The normal addClickHandler implementation doesn't work well on mobile browsers because of the built-in 300ms click delay.

Comment: Which handlers? Label has almost all the same handlers as ButtonBase, including HasAllTouchHandlers and HasAllGestureHandlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button base takes a cell, and flowpanel is not a cell and your code for compound button is wrong as it does not sends a cell to its parent.

Proper code is

```
public class CompoundButton<C> extends ButtonBase<C>
{
   protected CompoundButton( ButtonCellBase<C> cell )
   {
        super( cell );
   }
}
```